# Spark ClassNotFoundException running the master

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have downloaded and built Spark 0.80 using `sbt/sbt assembly`.  It was successful. However when running `./bin/start-master.sh` the following error is seen in the log file

```
Spark Command: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -cp :/shared/spark-0.8.0-incubating-bin-hadoop1/conf:/shared/spark-0.8.0-incubating-bin-hadoop1/assembly/target/scala-2.9.3/spark-assembly-0.8.0-incubating-hadoop1.0.4.jar
/shared/spark-0.8.0-incubating-bin-hadoop1/assembly/target/scala-2.9.3/spark-assembly_2.9.3-0.8.0-incubating-hadoop1.0.4.jar -Djava.library.path= -Xms512m -Xmx512m org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip mellyrn.local --port 7077 --webui-port 8080

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/deploy/master/Master
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

**Update**: after doing sbt **clean** (per suggestion below) it is running: see screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be a number of things which cause this error which are not specific to Spark:

1. Bad build, `sbt clean compile` that puppy again.
2. You have a cached dependency in your .ivy2 cache which conflicts with a dependency of that project version of Spark. Empty your cache and try again.
3. Your project which is building on Spark has a library version which conflicts with a dependency of Spark. That is, Spark may dependency on "foo-0.9.7" while your project put in "foo-0.8.4".

Try looking at those first.

Comment: I am not familiar with ivy2 dependency mgr - how to carry out emptying the cache as you mention in #2?